# Is there any android sdk documentation for ibm watson

Tags: android, chatbot, ibm-watson

I'm trying to write a chatbot in Android using the `ibm watson`. I installed the SDK, but I can't really find any proper documentation for the associated methods and functions. All I could find were tutorials regarding `Conversation` which belongs to the previous form of `ibm cloud`. Any links to tutorials or documentation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this link & see if it helps: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-android-watson-chatbot#build-a-voice-enabled-android-chatbot

Comment: And also this repo: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/chatbot-watson-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of instructions in this link: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/use-watson-android-sdk-in-android-studio/

Also, there`s a API Reference in this link: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator. Hereyou can check in the corner top right the language (for Android you can check for Java).

Comment: to be honest, i checked out all of these in the first try but none of them could provide a very in depth documentation about the methods that may be used in android. Best i can do now is cloning their git and try to deduce it on the go.